# I am trying to find out screen resolution on my MacBook

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, safari

I have a MacBook Pro 13". It is 3 years old. In `System Preferences > Display` there is nothing where I can change or see my screen resolution -- (I see you answered one user - go to System Preferences where one would find a list of resolutions and highlighted is yours) -- I do not have any options there.

Comment: If you're just looking for what the resolution is and not trying to change it, you can go to http://www.whatismyscreenresolution.com/

Answer (score 3):

It's there, just somewhat hidden. On newer versions of OS X it looks like this by default:

[image]

You need to select **Scaled** in order to see these options.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Apple Menu and select `About This Mac` -> `More Info...` -> `Displays`. It will show your resolution on that screen.